# Which app launched my app?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, uri, url-scheme

I have an Android app and have registered a custom URL scheme. Is it possible to get what app launched my app (e.g. Facebook, Chrome etc...)? At the moment, I can only find how to get the URL that was clicked but not the actual app that launched mine. Can I do this or am I chasing something not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. 
Unless, of course, you have defined a proprietary protocol where the calling activity includes the name of itself in the intent, and you are in control also of the calling applications. Obviously this would not work for cases such as finding out if Chrome or Facebook called you as you don't control these apps.

You might have some limited success using `ActivityManager.getRecentTasks()` and try to find out which app is #2 in the task list, but that API is deprecated in Lollipop, and can not be trusted on older platforms either, apps can choose to be excluded from recent tasks, your app could be spawning a new task vs be part of the calling apps task, etc.